# How to display rails API call data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m completely new to rails,  I want to create a simple article search application that would use the Guardian API and just display the news titles. I have a ready model responsible for queries, but I don’t  know how to make a controller and a view with a search form  that would trigger the model to display searched titles. It just needs to work like this: a user enters the page,  fills in the search form and views the news titles. I’m using httparty gem.

Model file:

```rb
class GuardianApi < ApplicationRecord

    include HTTParty
    BASE_URL ="https://content.guardianapis.com/search?"
    API_PARTIAL_URL = "api-key=#{ENV['GUARDIAN_API_KEY']}"

    def query
        request = HTTParty.get(BASE_URL+@search_format+API_PARTIAL_URL).to_json
        @request_hash = JSON.parse(request)
    end

    def initialize(user_search_input)
        @search_format = "q=#{user_search_input.gsub(" ", "%20")}&"
    end

    def print_titles
        @request_hash["response"]["results"].each do |article|
            puts article["webTitle"]
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: So, what you've got there is not really a model.  In Rails, models are used to store data in your applications database, Views are used to display and collect data from users, and Controllers are used to map actions triggered by the url.   It seems like what you want to do is just get results from a third party db and display to the user.  You can do that, but you may not need all the overhead of rails for that, since you're not really using it.

Answer (score 0):

First create an api consumer class:

```
# app/clients/guardian_api_client.rb
class GuardianApiClient
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://content.guardianapis.com'
  format :json

  def initialize(**options)
    @options = {
      "api-key" => ENV['GUARDIAN_API_KEY']
    }.merge(options)
  end

  def search(q)
    response = self.class.get('/search', @options.merge(
      q: q
    ))
    if response.success?
      response["results"]
    else
      [] # @todo add error handling
    end
  end
end
```

This is not really a model per say. Rather its a class that does one job - talking to the external API. This makes it easy to mock it for tests. Also you are including HTTParty in your class but you're still using it in the clumsy procedural way which makes it pretty pointless. If you want to do procedural just use Net::HTTP and skip the overhead.

Then a form to create the search query:

```
# app/views/search/search.html.erb
<%= form_with(url: '/search') do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_input :q %>
  <%= f.submit 'search' %>
<% end %>
```

And a controller to handle it:

```
class SearchController
  # GET /search
  def search
    @results = GuardianApiClient.new.search(params[:q])
  end
end
```

You can then list the results in the view:

```
<%= if @results.any? %>
  <ul>
  <% @results.each do |r| %>
    <li><%= r["webTitle"] %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% else %>
  <p>No results</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I followed your instructions, maybe I'm just doing something incorrectly but I get no results, could you tell me why is that ? I wrote the if statement in the app/views/search/search.html.erb .